# Do coproducts of infinity-groupoids commute with pullbacks?

Tags: higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits

As stated in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89444/do-disjoint-unions-and-fiber-products-commute) question, coproducts commute with pullbacks in the category of sets.

Let $Grpd_{\infty}$ denote the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids. Do coproducts commute with pullbacks in $Grpd_{\infty}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do, if you mean what is meant in the question you linked, but it is misleading to describe this property as "coproducts commute with pullbacks", say instead "pullback along a fixed morphism preserves coproducts", or "pullback *functors* preserve coproducts", or with more jargon, "coproducts are universal".

More generally, colimits are universal and this is one of the defining properties of an $\infty$-topos. See the discussion in section 6.1 of Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory*, specifically proposition 6.1.3.10.

---

EDIT: Thanks to Marc Hoyois for pointing out an absent minded mistake in a previous version!

The thing I would call "coproducts commuting with pullbacks", is the following property: given diagrams $X_i \to Z_i \leftarrow Y_i$, the canonical morphism $\coprod_i X_i \times_{Z_i} Y_i \to (\coprod_i X_i) \times_{\coprod_i Z_i} \coprod_i Y_i$ is an isomorphism (or equivalence, if you prefer that term). This also holds in spaces and indeed in every $\infty$-topos. More generally, in $\infty$-toposes coproducts commute with limits over connected categories.

Comment: Coproducts do commute with pullbacks in any ∞-topos. In your example you forgot that the pullback is over $*\amalg *$.

Comment: That was careless of me. Thanks for pointing it out, @MarcHoyois.